# Reading file contents from Windows gadget

Tags: javascript, windows-desktop-gadgets

I would like to create Windows Sidebar gadget which reads text file content, parses it content and presents it in nice form. Unfortunately I stuck in "reads text file content" part. I have no idea how can I do it. Obtaining System.Shell.Item works but how can I than read file content?

Answer (score 1):

Check this snippet:

```
var fs = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
var file = fs.OpenTextFile("C:\\yourFile.txt", 1, false, 0);
var text = file.ReadLine();
//First line of text stored in var "text"
```

**More info:** http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/czxefwt8%28v=vs.85%29.aspx